# Linux Guest on VirutalBox cant access local server but can access internet

Tags: linux, windows, virtualbox

I have a Linux guest running in VirtualBox on a Windows computer.. If I try to access outside sites from the VM, like yahoo.com, cnn.com etc it works great but if I try to access local servers I can't connect to them or ping them.. what can this be?

Comment: Try to see whether this behaviour persists if you change the Network configuration from NAT to bridged. Careful, under "bridged", you will have to select the interface your host is currently using, wifi, ethernet, whatever.

Comment: now I can ping it but if I try to ssh into a server it hang but if I do it from the host it ok?

Comment: how do you authenticate to the ssh server? Password? Cryptographic key? Does the ssh server have any restriction in place (AllowUser, DenyUser...)

Comment: I have a account and the password.. it works from the host so I dont know why it woul not work from the VM

Comment: Can you ping the ssh server? If so, then it's a different problem than the one you started out with.

Comment: now I can ping it but just cant ssh in yea

Comment: I opened a new issue that maybe you can help with.. I want to gtive you create for this [link]http://superuser.com/questions/669456/runnig-viruatbox-linux-guest-can-ssh-in-to-a-redhat-server

Answer (score 0):

Have your try that ? [How to access my local server on my VirtualBox virtual machine?](https://superuser.com/questions/74709/how-to-access-my-local-server-on-my-virtualbox-virtual-machine)

Comment: no the guest can getto the internet.. it looks like it cant see local ip addess

Comment: Ok I mistranslated. Sorry

Answer (score 0):

I ran into a similar situation while doing some testing.  An easy solution is to use two network interfaces in your VM, a NAT connection to get out to the internet and a localhost only connection.  It takes a little more work to setup but should solve your problem.

Comment: no the issue is that I cant get to the internet but could not get to my firms servers... now I can ping them but cant access them

Comment: So the host Windows machine can get to all services on your firm's servers that you need but it's the VM on that Windows machine that can't get to those servers?